# Which HW timer is used on call to hrtimer/timer_create()?

Tags: timer, linux-device-driver, hardware

I implement a driver for HW timers.

Yet, it seems that there is already interface for HW timers, so I am not sure that such driver is actually needed. I see the following in kernel and in userspace:

1. hrtimer in kernel:

   ```
   int hrtimer_start(struct hrtimer *timer, ktime_t time,
                 enum hrtimer_mode mode);
   ```
2. timer_create() in userspace:

   ```
    int timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent *sevp, timer_t *timerid)
   ```

Yet, I don't see in these APIs any mention of the actual HW timer number.

So , which HW timer number is actually used on calling these APIs ?

For example, on call to timer_create(), which HW timer is used  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the timer_create() syscall internally uses hrtimer (hrtimer is a high res timer).

In MACHINE_START() macro of your board file we pass a timer, which will be used for clock events and this clock is used by hrtimer.
also refer http://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers this should provide more info.

Comment: Is it that the kernel expose a single HW timer for application usage ? This same HW timer is used in all calls for timer_create()  ? Thx

Comment: on a single core machine yes same timer will be used for calls to timer_create().